# How to navigate in groups (not tabs) in tool windows

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I'm trying to use Intellij Idea only with the keybord.
How can I navigate between groups/panels (don't know the exact term) within a tab of a tool window?

For example in the Debug tool window → tab debugger how to switch from the Frames panel to Variables panel using only the keybord?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsnLI.png)

There is a mapping on `Alt + ->` or `Alt + <-` to navigate between tabs within a tool window.
But I can't find a way to navigate within the panels of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

i use linux, but maybe `windows key + tab`or more simple you can map the shortcut from your keybord in the windows settings

Comment: `windows key + tab` is bound to switch between applications in Windows. Mapping a keybord shortcut to an action could be a solution. The problem is I don't know the action to define the shortcut for.